# clearTextField() is not working in UIAutomator

Tags: android-uiautomator

i am new bee to uiautomator and when i am trying to clear the text field text with clearTextField() its not at all clearing. Can some one guide me how can i do this.

tried in this way also

`while(!"".equals(obj.getText())
obj.clearTextField();`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: obj.clearTextField() method is clearing a text field when "selectall" option is available. if "selectall" option is hiding at the top unable to clear the text field. Can someone help me how can i clear the entire text field at once.

Comment: I don't know about clearTextField() but you can try just editing the text to ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, we can't get the text from a password edittext. Unfortunally clearTextField() does not work on API 18 so:

```
obj.getText() = ""
obj.getText().lenght() = 0
```

My solution, not very beautifull i know, is:

```
private static void clearText(UiDevice uiDevice, UiObject textBox) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
    int estimatedLength = 30;
    textBox.clickBottomRight();
    for (int i = 0; i < estimatedLength; i++) {
        uiDevice.pressDelete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code :

```
String text = obj.getText();
obj.clickBottomRight();
for (int i=0;i<text.length();i++) {
    UiDevice.getInstance().pressDelete();
}
obj.setText("some-text");
```